# PoSH - display ultra-wide table in Powershell ISE?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I am trying to view, in table format, a CSV that has 75 columns.  This file occasionally has new fields added, so I want to be able to see all of the fields by scrolling over in the ISE.

It appears that the ISE will only show up to the first 120 characters, no matter how many fields there are.  -Force does not help.

Here's an example that exhibits the same behavior.  Even if you list out each property in the select, it only shows 120 characters.

```
get-childitem c:\windows|select *|format-table
```

I tried out-gridview, but that's limited to 30 fields.

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
get-childitem c:\windows|select PSParentPath,PSChildName,PSDrive,PSProvider,PSIsContainer,Name,Mode |format-table -AutoSize
```

`-Autosize` is the key. Also, `Select *` won't work as ISE will optimize the output to fit it properly. You need to explicitly mention the columns you want to see.

Comment: Odd - when I do that, it still lops off at 120 characters. `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\windows ocsetup_cbs_install_OEMHelpCustomization.txt C       Microsoft.Powe...`

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with the screen buffer.  Trying to figure out how to reset it in the ISE.